# How to support new Google's 2018/2019 security&performance updates in ReactNative

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Google announce in 2017 on [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html) page that new updates will be made in the performance and security areas. Therefore, 2 main points will have to be taken care of from the second part of 2018:

> In the second half of 2018, Play will require that new apps and app updates target a recent Android API level. This will be required for new apps in August 2018, and for updates to existing apps in November 2018. This is to ensure apps are built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance.

and

> In August 2019, Play will require that new apps and app updates with native libraries provide 64-bit versions in addition to their 32-bit versions.

In the same time, [ReactNative official page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-building-from-source.html) says that the latest API support is 23 and upgrades may lead to unpredictable behaviour.

Does anyone know how should this upgrade be handled or if FB announced any update on this area ?